# How to drag a line in ios using UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, uigesturerecognizer

I am writing a program where the user will drag a line from one `UILabel` to another.  I created a `UIView` subclass called DragView, and overrode the `drawRect` method.   I made the `UIView` a subview of the `RootController` view.   The `DragView` is definitely visible, the `drawRect` method is definitely being called, but no line is visible.

These are (what I think are) the relevant pieces of code.

```
//DragView.m

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (context == nil)
    {
        context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    }

    if (_drawLineFlag)
    {

        CGContextSetLineWidth(context,2.0); 
        CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGFloat components[] = {0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0};
        CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);

        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,color);

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context,_startX, _startY);

        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,_currentX,_currentY);

        CGContextStrokePath(context);   
    } 
}
```

DrawProgramAppDelegate

```
- (void) initializeUI
{
.....

    dragView = [[DragView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,1024.0f,768.0f)] ;
    [view addSubview: dragView];
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [dragView addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
.....

}
```

The event handler is:

```
- (void) handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) recognizer             
{
    CGPoint point = [recognizer translationInView:dragView];

    [dragView setCurrentX:point.x];
    [dragView setCurrentY:point.y];
    [dragView setDrawLineFlag:YES];

    [view bringSubviewToFront:drawView];
    [dragView drawRect:CGRectMake (0.0f,0.0f,768.0f, 1024.0f)];
}
```

Many thanks for your help.

Jon

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you are trying to draw a path (you should take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481287/how-to-create-a-path-using-coregraphics)). Here it seems you just draw a line from the last point to the current point

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(context,_startX, _startY);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,_currentX,_currentY);
```

which given the frequency of the call would only draw a tiny line.

You should not call drawRect:

```
[dragView drawRect:CGRectMake (0.0f,0.0f,768.0f, 1024.0f)];
```

You should tell the system the view needs displaying

```
[dragView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Also you should check the gesture recognizer state, defined as

```
typedef enum {
   UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible,
   UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan,
   UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged,
   UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded,
   UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled,
   UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed,
   UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized = UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded
} UIGestureRecognizerState;
```

And possibly only draw if the state is `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` or `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`

Comment: How to detect and find the line? i want to hightlight when i tap on drwan line. This my code base (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811490/draw-line-using-uipinchgeusturerecognizer).