# Detect (Using UITapGeusture) and Drag Line (Using UIPanGesture)

Tags: ios, core-graphics, line, draw, drag

I want to drag a drawn line which is done by [Me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811490/draw-line-using-uipinchgeusturerecognizer/25883973?noredirect=1#comment40547589_25883973). The below code snippet working fine with help of stack overflow user answer.

//My instances in .h file

```
CGPoint location1,location2;
LineView* l;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   l = [[LineView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
   [self.view addSubview:l];
   UIPinchGestureRecognizer *linepinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]    
   initWithTarget:l action:@selector(handleLinePinch:)];
   [l addGestureRecognizer:linepinch];
}


- (void)handleLinePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    NSUInteger num_touches = [gesture numberOfTouches];

    // save locations to some instance variables, like `CGPoint location1, location2;`
    if (num_touches >= 1) {
       location1 = [gesture locationOfTouch:0 inView:l];
    }
    if (num_touches >= 2) {
       location2 = [gesture locationOfTouch:1 inView:l];
    }
    [l drawRect:location1 Loc2:location2];
    [l setNeedsDisplay];

}


LineView.m

- (void)drawRect:(CGPoint)location1 Loc2:(CGPoint)location2 {

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, location1.x, location1.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, location2.x, location2.y);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

The above code snippet working fine but i want to drag this line by using UITapGeustureRecognizer or someother.thanks in advance.

Comment: Tap gestures are not suitable for what you are trying to achieve. You should use a pan gesture.

Comment: Yes, But first to detect the line object i would like to use tap gesture.

Comment: So you want to perform two taps and then it to draw the line between them?

Comment: No i don't think so, single tap only.If user tap on first point means, he can extend the from that point to user's end point.Same as for end point of drawn line.But the line has to be straight line.If user touch on mid point of line means, he can drag the line without extend/edit the line. Similar to Osirix iPad App

Comment: First thing is How to detect the line?